# How to implement parallel selenium processing

Tags: python, selenium, rest, parallel-processing, joblib

I had this question asked earlier [inactive and now deleted] but didn't phrase it right. And I'm trying to improve on that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO**: Automate certain tasks [with selenium] (Restful API)

- go to website
- search for task and if found, open task in a new tab (switch to new tab - tab1)
- click on 'seen' and then close the tab (close - switch to tab0) [this doesn't return anything]
- refresh the first tab (tab0) so 'seen' automatically updates (I think this works by session/cache)-  there's a side column that shows all seen tasks.
- And at the end of all tasks (tab0), click on 'done' under completed tasks which returns a booking code.

**WHAT I HAVE RUNNING:**

```
class SomeClass(SomeOtherClass):
  def do_tasks(self, selections):
       booking_code = None
       task_done = 0

       driver = self.connect() #spawns a chrome browser

       #I want the below for loop to run in parallel

       for task in tasks:
           try:
               #check_if_task_is_in_search_result_&_then_open_in_new_tab
               #do_something
               task_done += 1
               #close_tab
           except:
               #handle_something

           driver.close()
           driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
           driver.refresh()

       try:
           check = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'xxxx'))).click()
       except NoSuchElementException as e:
           log_error(str(e))
       except TimeoutException as e:
           log_error(str(e))
           
       else:
           booking_code = str(driver.find_element_by_class_name("number").text).split(':')[1]
           driver.quit()

       return task_done, booking_code
```

This is sequential and takes roughly 5 mins for 5 tasks.

### GETTING IT TO RUN IN PARALLEL

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR** - bring out the for-loop section to a new method - `do_task`.
Import: `from joblib import Parallel, delayed`

```
class SomeClass(SomeOtherClass):
  def do_task(self, task):
      driver = self.connect() #spawns a chrome browser
      try:
         #do_something
         task_done += 1
      except:
         #handle_something
      
      return task_done, driver 

 

  def get_booking_code(self, driver):
      try:
           check = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'xxxx'))).click()
      except NoSuchElementException as e:
           log_error(str(e))
      else:
           booking_code = str(driver.find_element_by_class_name("number").text).split(':')[1]
           driver.quit()
      return booking_code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tasks = [
        ['task1'],
        ['task2']
  ]
  
    b = SomeClass(site='https://somesite.com/') #chrome connects to this via the self.connect()
    completed_tasks, driver = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(b.do_task)(task) for task in tasks)
    booking_code = b.get_booking_code(driver)
    print(completed_tasks, booking_code)
```

It doesn't run. It spawns a blank chrome browser and closes immediately.

Traceback as below:

```
  completed_tasks, driver = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(b.do_task)(task) for task in tasks)  
  File "--\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1054, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "--\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 933, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "--\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 542, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "--\python\python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "c:\users\okwud\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created       
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

Comment: The easiest explanation I've seen to run selenium workers in parallel. [link](https://gist.github.com/wooddar/df4c89f381fa20ce819e94782dc5bc04)

Comment: You cannot get true concurrency with Selenium. Try Pyppeteer.

Comment: @pguardiario, thanks but I checked the package and it would require that I re-write my entire code (what is shown here is 1 in 7 similar code), so I might be considering it as a last resort. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this solved yesterday(tasks running in parallel) but I'm now facing an entirely new challenge for which a new post would be made to address it.

**How I got the tasks to run in parallel *(using my second code - 'what I have tried so far')*:**

```
import multiprocessing

#code excluded on purpose

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tasks = [
        ['task1'],
        ['task2']
  ]
    b = SomeClass()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as p:
        p.map(b.do_task, tasks)
```

The `do_task` method only returns the number of task done (this is an arbitary return value)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should create up separate 'SomeClass' object for every task and then call up the respective functions in parallel, because there is self.connect() and driver.quit() statement inside the definitions being executed in parallel. Please try either with creating up separate class object for every parallel task or make up a common session and remove driver.quit() from parallel executions methods.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit, but I simply can't put together your explanation to code. Can you explain a bit more?